# PyMySQL Data types

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqldatatypes, pymysql

I'm new in Python and trying to learn MySQL

as we import pymysql

```
import pymysql
from datetime import datetime

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = '',
    database = 'test'
)
mycursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO led (id,name,date) VALUES (%i,%s,%d,)"
```

my question is if we have the values of datatypes id = %i, name =%s and date = %d , what are the `%?`  of datetime, time and timestamp..?

I got errors on inserting data while i don not know that exact %? of the all datatypes. if some one has link to learn these datatypes values %? please share the link or if you get my question please answer... I am inserting data i use functions but got NoModuleError. now(), current_date(),datetime()

**please let me know that what are the `%?`  of datetime, time and timestamp..?**

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume '%s' since a properly formatted `DATE` literal is indisposable from '2024-01-25'.  (Etc.)  If you need, for example, the year last, you will have to convert it before or after feeding it to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the format ("%s") [paramstyle](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle) for value placeholders in queries, the placeholder is *always* "%s", regardless of the type of the value being substituted.

```py
cursor.execute(
    """INSERT INTO t (a, b, c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""",
    (1, 'a', datetime.date(2024, 1, 26))
)
```

Type-specific placeholders like "%d" or "%i" are used in [printf-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), (`spam = 'I am %d years old' % 42`). This looks similar to value placeholders in queries, but it is not the same.  This technique (and similar like f-strings and `str.format`) should not be used to construct SQL queries because it does not provide any defence against SQL injection.